# Assign value into Dictionary that has a key type of <Tuple<int,int> C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, tuples, key-value

I writing code to generate a grid that is supposed to be a graphical editor. The grid values are being contained in a dictionary. This is my method for generating my dictionary object to give you an idea of what I am working with.

```
public Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, string> GenerateTable(int _x, int _y)
        {
            int total = _x * _y;
            var grid = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, string>(); //!Might need this later!

            for (int i = 1; i <= _x; i++) // outer loop is column 
            {
                for (int ii = 1; ii <= _y; ii++) // Inner loop is row -
                {
                    grid.Add(Tuple.Create(i, ii), "O");
                }
            }
            return grid; // Should have same amount of elements as int total
        }
```

I have another method where I want to change one element in my dictionary, because I am using a key of Tuple I don't know what to provide in the index to change the value. This is the other method.

```
 public void ColorPixel(Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, string> _table, int _x, int _y, string _c)
        {
            foreach(var pixel in _table
                .Where(k => k.Key.Item1 == _x && k.Key.Item2 == _y))
            {

            }


            //var tbl = _table.
            //    Where(t => t.Key.Item1 == _x && t.Key.Item2 == _y)
            //    .Select(t => t.Value == _c);

        }
```

Does anyone know how I change the element in the dictionary by accessing it's key of type Tuple ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? `dict[Tuple.Create(1, 2)] = value` should work?

Comment: @knittl I simply want to change one of the elements in the dictionary. But because my dictionary is Tuple<int, int>, string I don't know what to type to access it's key.

Comment: You access it with a tuple, as I wrote in my comment above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Tuple` types are "structurally comparable". Which means that to access the value in dictionary keyed by one, you create a new instance of the tuple, and access the value any way you see fit (indexer, `TryGetValue` etc.).

```
var key = Tuple.Create(x, y);
var value = dictionary[key];
```

Comment: Thanks your code worked a treat. The second line is the other way round, I want to assign value to dictionary[key]. Not knowing that I had to create tuple was what I didn't know.

Comment: Just make sure that `key` already exists in your table, in case your table could be sparse.

Comment: The "structural comparability" is not really relevant here. The relevant info is that `Tuple<,>` overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode` and provides a coordinate-wise implementation. That is the same behavior as the "structural **equatable**" implementation. The "comparable" thing could be relevant if you wanted a `SortedDictionary<Tuple<,>,>`, for example.

Answer (score 4):

I know this thread is old, but with new C#7 you can do something like:

```
var grid = new Dictionary<ValueTuple<int, int>, string>();

grid.Add((1,1),"value");
```

then you can read it using:

```
string value=grid[(1,1)];
```

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

Per Avner's comment, you shouldn't use Linq for this in this way. This is a classic mistake that's often caused by the relative easy of writing Linq statements but hurts performance greatly, especially for dictionaries.

```
var keyToFind = Tuple.Create(_x, _y);
string pixelValueToUpdate;
_table.TryGetValue(keyTofind, out pixelValueToUpdate);
if (pixelValueToUpdate != null)
    pixelValueToUpdate = "New Value";
```

---

**Don't Use LINQ**

```
var pixelValue = _table
    .Where(pixel => pixel.Key.Item1 == _x && pixel.Key.Item2 == _y)
    .FirstOrDefault(pixel => pixel.Value);
pixelValue = "NewValue;
```

That should do it. Since your `Tuple<int, int>` is a key into a dictionary, you can only have one pixel with a set of `(x, y)` coordinates, hence, there's no need to iterate over the entire table.

Comment: This version simply treats the `Dictionary` as an `IEnumerable` of key/value pairs, which loses the quick lookup properties.

Comment: For the record, I wrote a lambda expression to see how it would work. I've gone with cynic's solution because I don't want to loop through the entire collection when I already have the co-ordinates.

Comment: @nickgowdy understood. Avner was right, though about my solution. Duly noted.